# How can I put a custom header for websocket handshake with boost beast

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, request-headers, beast

How to send custom headers in the first handshake that occurs in the WebSocket protocol with boost beast ?

I want to use custom header in my initial request "x-custome-id : xxxxx".

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and show us what you tried using code, including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show what part isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the candidate solution as https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/70.
But, this occurs compiler error with boost 1.69.
This issue also fixed with the solution https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/1470.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to put the custum header somthing like this

You might want to change a few details here and there

```
ws_.async_handshake_ex(host, <endpoint>,
            [<somerequestname>](request_type& reqHead) {
                reqHead.insert(http::field::<sometype>,xxxxx);},
            bind(Some handler));
```

**Note:**

you will have theses details like `host`, `endpoint`,etc

This is what you want to get right - `reqHead.insert(http::field::<sometype>,xxxxx);}` Explore the option suitable for you in `http::field::<sometype>`
explore the [enum class field : unsigned short](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/boost/beast/http/field.hpp) for this.

Comment: Thak you for your kindly help!